# iSCSI initiator APIs

Tags: python, iscsi, open-iscsi

Situation: Writing an automatic file sorter to search for files in iSCSI connected disks.
My program will be sitting on a client machine (iSCSI initiator), connected to a server (iSCSI target).

Problem: I could use system calls to call on the system's (Linux) `open-iscsi` command. However, the `open-iscsi` package refused to install due to "incompatible kernel".

What I tried to do: Searched for iSCSI initiators written in Python (the language my program is written in). I found two - `infi.iscsiapi` and `python-iscsi`. Problem is, `python-iscsi` has not been updated in 2 years; and I had trouble getting `infi.iscsiapi` to work properly.

Question: Are there any other Python based iSCSI initiators that you know I am able to use?

Additional information: Feel free to suggest other methods of connecting to an iSCSI target through a Python script, or even using other languages. As long as the process of connecting to the iSCSI target can be automated + it can be called from a Python script, it is good enough for me.

Comment: Wouldn't you be querying the file system? How would what you're doing be different for SSD, SATA or SAS disks?

Comment: @joeqwerty I've updated my question to make my situation clearer.

Comment: Just use the supported method for your specific Linux distribution.

Comment: @Michael I had a problem with getting the supported method to work, which is why I am posting this question...

Comment: So what was the problem? I see virtually nothing about it here.

Comment: It is addressed in the Problem in my question - the package could not be installed because of an incompatible kernel